# Remove comma(,) from string number in dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

I have a list of dictionary:: Sample data:: Like this I have n number of data.

```
datas = [{"_id":"1234as", "Total students":"123,321", "TotalPresent":"321,345"}, 
    {"_id":"1234asas","TotalStudents":"343,431","TotalPresent":"541,656"}]
```

**I tried**

```
for data in datas:
    for i in data.values():
        re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', i)
    datas.append(i)
```

I just want to remove comma(,) from TotalStudents and TotalPresent and replace the value in datas.

**Edit 1**

In my list of dictionary I also have value as::

```
datas = [{"_id":"1234as","Totalstudents":"123,321","TotalPresent":"321,345"},      
        {"_id":"1234asas","TotalStudents":"343,431","TotalPresent":"541,656"},
         {"_id":"9934 asas","TotalStudents":"NA","TotalPresent":""}]
```

Here, in key TotalStudents value is "NA" and TotalPresent is "". Is there a way to replace whereever  "NA" or "" appears replace with "0".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the values of specific keys, make sure that the keys are the same because the first dict in your example has `Total Students` but the second has `TotalStudents`.

Try this:

```
datas = [{"_id": "1234as", "Total Students": "123,321", "TotalPresent": "321,345"},
         {"_id": "1234asas", "Total Students": "343,431", "TotalPresent": "541,656"}]

for d in datas:
    d["Total Students"] = d["Total Students"].replace(",", "")
    d["TotalPresent"] = d["TotalPresent"].replace(",", "")

print(datas)
# output: [{'_id': '1234as', 'Total Students': '123321', 'TotalPresent': '321345'}, {'_id': '1234asas', 'Total Students': '343431', 'TotalPresent': '541656'}]
```

If you want to replace commas from all the keys, you can try (but bare in mind that in this case, all the values of your dict must be strings):

```
datas = [{"_id": "1234as", "Total Students": "123,321", "TotalPresent": "321,345"},
         {"_id": "1234asas", "Total Students": "343,431", "TotalPresent": "541,656"}]

for d in datas:
    for k in d:
        d[k] = d[k].replace(",", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the key,value pairs in the dictionaries. And after removing the comma replace the value for that key.

```
import re

datas = [{"_id": "1234as", "Total Students": "123,321", "TotalPresent": "321,345"},
         {"_id": "1234asas", "TotalStudents": "343,431", "TotalPresent": "541,656"}]


for data in datas:
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key, value)
        value = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', value)
        data[key] = value

print(datas)
```

Result

```
_id 1234as
Total Students 123,321
TotalPresent 321,345
_id 1234asas
TotalStudents 343,431
TotalPresent 541,656

[{'_id': '1234as', 'Total Students': '123321', 'TotalPresent': '321345'}, 
 {'_id': '1234asas', 'TotalStudents': '343431', 'TotalPresent': '541656'}]
```

This is a way to make your code working, and thus always replacing all values. If necessary you need to add your own checks to make it smarter.

**EDIT**

To catch the "NA" and "" values I have added some if statements. It's simple and stays close to your own code.

```
import re

datas = [{"_id":"1234as","TotalStudents":"123,321","TotalPresent":"321,345"},
        {"_id":"1234asas","TotalStudents":"343,431","TotalPresent":"541,656"},
         {"_id":"9934 asas","TotalStudents":"NA","TotalPresent":""}]


for data in datas:
    print(data)
    for key, value in data.items():

        if key == "TotalStudents":
            if value == "NA":
                value =  "0"
            else:
                value = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', value)
        elif key == "TotalPresent":
            if not value:
                value = "0"
            else:
                value = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', value)

        data[key] = value

print()
for data in datas:
    print(data)
```

Result

```
{'_id': '1234as', 'TotalStudents': '123321', 'TotalPresent': '321345'}
{'_id': '1234asas', 'TotalStudents': '343431', 'TotalPresent': '541656'}
{'_id': '9934 asas', 'TotalStudents': '0', 'TotalPresent': '0'}
```

To make the code more efficient you can place the new values directly in data. In this case you don't replace the "_id" anymore with it's own value.

```
import re

datas = [{"_id":"1234as","TotalStudents":"123,321","TotalPresent":"321,345"},
        {"_id":"1234asas","TotalStudents":"343,431","TotalPresent":"541,656"},
         {"_id":"9934 asas","TotalStudents":"NA","TotalPresent":""}]


for data in datas:
    print(data)
    for key, value in data.items():

        if key == "TotalStudents":
            if value == "NA":
                data[key] = "0"
            else:
                data[key] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', value)
        elif key == "TotalPresent":
            if not value:
                data[key] = "0"
            else:
                data[key] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', value)

print()
for data in datas:
    print(data)
```

Comment: I found your answer helpful for the question asked and will accept this as an answer. But before I close this thread can you please have a look for the case as mentioned in the edited question

Comment: I have added a simple adjustment and an extra step for some simple efficiency improvement. I hope it helps. Be aware that you have a typo in your data: 'Totalstudents'.

Comment: Changed 0 to "0" to put strings back into data

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` does not work in-place - it does return altered `str`. More generally as `str`s are immutable functions processing them are not working in-place. Solution using `re.sub` might looks following way:

```
import re
datas = [{"_id":"1234as","Total Students":"123,321","TotalPresent":"321,345"},
{"_id":"1234asas","TotalStudents":"343,431","TotalPresent":"541,656"}]
cleandatas = []
for data in datas:
    cleandatas.append({k:re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', v) for k,v in data.items()})
print(cleandatas)
```

Output:

```
[{'_id': '1234as', 'Total Students': '123321', 'TotalPresent': '321345'}, {'_id': '1234asas', 'TotalStudents': '343431', 'TotalPresent': '541656'}]
```

I used `dict`-comprehension to create new cleaned `dict`s